# How to create nested user controls in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have the following classes in my vb.net application:

Form1
Usercontrol1
LnkLabel

Usercontrol1 is a user control , and doesnt contain any extra code. LnkLabel is a class that inherits Forms.Label. Its code is goven below:

```
Public class LnkLabel
Inherits Label
Sub clk handles me.click
Process.start(text)
End sub
End class
```

When I add an Instance of LnkLabel to usercontrol1, i get an error "type LnkLabel is not defined"
There are three instances of the error in uc1.designer.vb.How can I solve these Errors?
Note: 
Visual Studio 2010
.Net FW 3.5

Edit:
The usercontrol1 donot contain any code that might be causing the error. It is just a new usercontrol added to the project.
LnkLabel is added to UC1 by the designer, not by using code at runtime.
The class name is LnkLabel, and not "LinkLabel".

Comment: by `instance of usercontrol1` do you mean dynamically at runtime, or are you trying to add UC2 to the UC1 in the designer?

Comment: UC1 is added to UC2 by designer, not dynamically at runtime. I have also edited the question.

Comment: This may be a silly question but are you sure you `build` again your project? And also try renaming `Form1` to something like `MyForm`.

Comment: I dont understand how renaming the form will work. It has got nothing to do with the usercontrols.

Comment: @Arman : I cant build the project because there are 3 errors in my errorlist ( in usercontrol2.designer.vb)

Comment: Be sure that both usercontrols have a public parameterless constructor: Public Sub New()

Comment: And save all files, close project, reopen and rebuild.

Comment: As i said, the usercontrols are freshly added to the project. Everything is default. And it makes no sense: i can see Usercontrol.vb in the solution explorer, and in the error list it says  " type uc1 isnt defined"

Comment: @farizrahman4u Please append all of your code.

Comment: @farizrahman4u You have said you can see the user controls in the solution explorer, but can you see them Both in the toolbox? Again, change your form name as I stated above to avoid root namespace conflict which in some case is the problem.

Comment: does 'add an instance of usercontrol1 to usercontrol2` mean you are trying to redesign UC1 to also include UC2 and therefore all this is taking place in the **usercontrol2 designer**?  If so, the error probably has to do with project/solution config...check project dependencies and/or migrate UC1 into the UC2 project/

Comment: Are the controls in their own dll? If not they should be and it should be built and you should appear in the tool box to use them at design time. You can mess VS up on occasion by making a change to controls dll. Usually a clean and rebuild sorts that. Occasionally the .designer file in which they are used gets stuffed and you have to start again or manually edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the easiest way to resolve this type of issue is to open the Designer.vb file directly.

To do this, choose Show All Files from the Project menu, then expand UserControl2. Double-click on the UserControl2.Designer.vb file.

You should also be able to get there by double-clicking on the error in the compile errors list.

Once there, search for the definition of UserControl1 or uc1, whatever it may be called (ensure you are in the type definition area, not the property assignment area).

Looking at the definition may give you an instant clue as to the problem (is it in the wrong namespace; did the name of the user control change after you created it, but the change was not propagated to this form; etc).

If it is not obvious what the issue is, use VS intellisense to help you get the right class. I usually clear the previous type definition and start typing the name I know it should be (i.e. UserControl), then select the appropriate value from Intellisense.

Selecting a different class (or correcting the class selection) will require a change to the control instatiation code and may also require a change to some of the properties (I usually just remove the properties I am unsure of and update the control directly in the designer).

Before you switch back to the designer, ensure that you save your changes and, if possible, compile the app.

Comment: There was a slight complication in the program that i forgot to mention. I have edited the question accorldingly.